# Appending a button

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to append a "remove" button to ul items on hover.  It seems to work, but I can't seem to get the button to align to the right of the screen.  Each time I try, it seems to go to the right and down one line.

Here is the full script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>remove button</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $( document ).ready( function() { 
                $("li").hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).append($("<a href='#'>(remove)</a>"));
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        $(this).find("a:last").remove();
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="mylist">
            <li id="item_4"><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>
            <li id="item_9"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
            <li id="item_2"><a href="http://www.bing.com">bing</a></li>
            <li id="item_5"><a href="http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a></li>
            <li id="item_8"><a href="http://www.ebay.com">ebay</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>remove button</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            li a.button {float:right;}

        </style>


        <script>
            $( document ).ready( function() { 
                $("li").hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).append($(" <a href='#' class='button'>(remove)</a>"));
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        $(this).find("a:last").remove();
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="mylist">
            <li id="item_4"><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>
            <li id="item_9"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
            <li id="item_2"><a href="http://www.bing.com">bing</a></li>
            <li id="item_5"><a href="http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a></li>
            <li id="item_8"><a href="http://www.ebay.com">ebay</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>remove button</title>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            a.button {float:right;}
        </style>

        <script>
            $( document ).ready( function() { 
                $("li").hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).append($(" <a href='#' class='button'>(remove)</a>"));
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        $(this).find("a:last").remove();
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="mylist">
            <li id="item_4"><a href="http://www.google.com">google</a></li>
            <li id="item_9"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a></li>
            <li id="item_2"><a href="http://www.bing.com">bing</a></li>
            <li id="item_5"><a href="http://www.youtube.com">youtube</a></li>
            <li id="item_8"><a href="http://www.ebay.com">ebay</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post your css as this will be causing the issue. My first thought is that you have display:block sent on your <a />s. Note you may want to include a space between the anchors

Comment: This page has no css at the moment. The script above is everything and I am testing in IE8.

Comment: It works for me : http://www.jsfiddle.net/txqhB/ you may have additional CSS. (I tested it on chrome and IE7)

Comment: I have just tested it in chrome and it works fine, but not in IE8.  The (remove) is one line below the item I hover over.

Comment: I don't have any additional script.  Please see the original question edit 2, that is a copy and paste of the script I have.  It does not have any external css files attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are in compatibility mode as IE8 displays correctly. Follow Baptiste Pernet's method but your css should be:

```
li a {float:left}

li a.button { float: right;}
```

This will stop IE7 and IE8 compat dropping the remove button to another line but you will need to make the 's contain the floats as in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xu6Q9/1/)

Comment: Strange, I added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> and it has started to work.  Why would IE8 be defaulting to compatibility mode of IE7?  If I add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"> the button goes down one line. but with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> it works as I want it to work.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out, I for some reason had intranet sites set to IE7 mode...

Comment: IE has wierd ideas - go to 'page -> compatibility view settings' and disable the options. May be that you are in your intranet zone which by default is forced into compatibility!!  Also you may want to include the fix just in case ;)

Comment: You know what this means, it means I am going to have to redo this site for IE8, because I thought I was developing on IE8 when infact I was developing on IE7.  (Feel like banging my head on the table...).

Answer (score 2):

try to add a a class to your button:

```
$(this).append($("<a href='#' class='button'>(remove)</a>"));
```

with this css :

```
li a.button { float: right;}
```

with this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/GWUZg/

Comment: For some reason, this does not work for me.  I have edited my original question to show the script with your css

Comment: It works in the link you provided, but it does not work when I try to add the same script to my webpage.

Comment: @oshirowanen : _doesn't work_ isn't a good way to explain yourself. Can you please be more precise ?

Comment: Yes, as explain in other comments to answers above, when i hover over an item, the (remove) appears to the right of the screen, but 1 line below the item I am hovering over, it should be on the same line as the item I hover over and to the right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me in Chrome, FF and IE8. What's your browser?

EDIT:
Try this:

```
<style>
    li { width:130px;}
</style>
```

in `<head>` and change script to:

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready( function() { 
            $("li").hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).append($("<a href='#' style='float:right;'>(remove)</a>"));
                }, 
                function () {
                    $(this).find("a:last").remove();
                }
            );
        });
</script>
```

Works for me on all browsers.
And if you want to align button to right of the screen just change `li { width:130px; }` to `li { width:100%; }`.

Comment: Yes, the script above works as it is, but I want to some how get the (remove) button to align to the right of the screen, on the same line as the item being hovered over, or maybe float to the right of the screen. Each time I try, it drops down one line. I am using IE8.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 <script>
        $( document ).ready( function() { 
            $("li").hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).append($("<a href='#' class='button'>(remove)</a>"));
                }, 
                function () {
                    $(this).find("a:last").remove();
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

and css will be ..

```
.button{position: relative; width: 760px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: right; }
```

and for more information try this link
[try this](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/csslayout.html)

Comment: I've just tried this, and the (remove) does not move from it's original location at all.